Polars Calculating Number of Concurrent Event in a Timeseries
I have a timeseries:
ts = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "start_index": [0, None, None, 3, None, None],
        "end_index": [4, None, None, 4, None, None],
        }
    )

for each timestamp index, I want to calculate the number of concurrent events. For example,

At timestamp 0, we have an event starting at the end of timestamp 0 and ends at the end of timestamp 4, for a span of [1, 2, 3, 4].
At timestamp 3 we have another event starting at end of timestamp 3 and ends at 4, for a span of [4].

The first event's span overlaps with the second event during timestamp 3-4 therefore the number of concurrent event at timestamp 4 is 2. We assign 0 to the observations that do not have an active event.
Expected output:
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ timestamp ┆ start_index ┆ end_index ┆ number_of_concurrent_event │
│ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---                        │
│ i64       ┆ i64         ┆ i64       ┆ i64                        │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 0           ┆ 4         ┆ 0                          │
│ 1         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1                          │
│ 2         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1                          │
│ 3         ┆ 3           ┆ 4         ┆ 1                          │
│ 4         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 2                          │
│ 5         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 0                          │
└───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────┘


Isn't start_index reduntant here? if not, could you give an example of the dataframe where start_index is not empty and not equal to timestamp?

Is timestamp guaranteed to be unique?

A signal analysis trick is to map all the start of events to +1 and the end
of events to -1 and cumulative sum everything between.
In your data, since your events can end simultaneously we’ll
need to step through a .value_counts() to grab the correct number of ending
events at a given timestamp.
This has the advantage of not needing to generate a sparser timeseries and only relies on the dense timepoints that already exist.
import polars as pl
from polars import col

ts = pl.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "start_index": [0, None, None, 3, None, None],
    "end_index": [4, None, None, 4, None, None],
})

print(
    ts
    .join(
        ts.select(
            col('end_index').filter(col('end_index').is_not_null())
            .value_counts()
        ).unnest('end_index'),
        left_on='timestamp',
        right_on='end_index',
        how='outer',
    )
    .select(
        *ts.columns,

        col('start_index').is_not_null().cast(pl.Int32)
        .add(col('count').mul(-1).fill_null(0))
        .shift(fill_value=0) # offsets the start/stop by 1 row
        .cum_sum()
        .alias('concurrent')
    )
    # shape: (6, 4)
    # ┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
    # │ timestamp ┆ start_index ┆ end_index ┆ concurrent │
    # │ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
    # │ i64       ┆ i64         ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
    # ╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
    # │ 0         ┆ 0           ┆ 4         ┆ 0          │
    # │ 1         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1          │
    # │ 2         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1          │
    # │ 3         ┆ 3           ┆ 4         ┆ 1          │
    # │ 4         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 2          │
    # │ 5         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 0          │
    # └───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────────┘

)


Here is a more generic approach if your data can have events that begin at the same start_index.
import polars as pl
from polars import col

ts = pl.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "start_index": [0, None, None, 3, None, None],
    "end_index": [4, None, None, 4, None, None],
})

print(
    pl.concat(
        items=[
            ts,

            ts.select( # count the starting indices
                col('start_index').value_counts()
                .struct.rename_fields(['timestamp', 'starts'])
            ).unnest('start_index'),

            ts.select( # count the ending indices
                col('end_index').value_counts()
                .struct.rename_fields(['timestamp', 'ends'])
            ).unnest('end_index'),
        ],
        how='align'
    )
    .drop_nulls('timestamp')
    .select(
        *ts.columns,
        concurrent=(
            pl.sum_horizontal(col('starts'), -1 * col('ends'))
            .shift(fill_value=0)
            .cum_sum()
        )
    )
)


I would start out creating a new frame that converts the start_index to end_index into individual rows. From that I'd do an outer_coalesce join to the original and then group by the timestamp taking the non-null count of the original_timestamp as the concurrent events.
(
    ts
    .filter(pl.col('start_index').is_not_null() & pl.col('end_index').is_not_null())
    .select(
        original_timestamp="timestamp", 
        timestamp=pl.int_ranges(
            pl.col('start_index')+1,
            pl.col('end_index')+1
            )
        )
    .explode('timestamp')
    .join(ts, 
          on='timestamp', 
          how='outer_coalesce'
          )
    .group_by('timestamp',maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col('start_index','end_index').drop_nulls().first(), 
        pl.col('original_timestamp').is_not_null().sum()
        )
)
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ timestamp ┆ start_index ┆ end_index ┆ number_of_concurrent_event │
│ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---                        │
│ i64       ┆ i64         ┆ i64       ┆ u32                        │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 0           ┆ 4         ┆ 0                          │
│ 1         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1                          │
│ 2         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 1                          │
│ 3         ┆ 3           ┆ 4         ┆ 1                          │
│ 4         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 2                          │
│ 5         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 0                          │
└───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────┘


I think this is basically the same as @Cameron-Riddell's approach - just expressed a little differently.
ts = ts.with_columns(starts = pl.col("start_index").is_not_null())

(
   ts.join(ts, left_on="timestamp", right_on="end_index", how="left")
     .rename({"starts_right": "ends"})
     .group_by("timestamp", maintain_order=True)
     .agg(
        pl.exclude("starts", "ends").first(),
        pl.col("starts", "ends").sum()
     )  
     .with_columns(
        concurrent = (pl.col("starts") + (pl.col("ends") * -1)).cum_sum().shift()
     )
)

shape: (6, 8)
┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────┬────────┬──────┬────────────┐
│ timestamp ┆ start_index ┆ end_index ┆ timestamp_right ┆ start_index_right ┆ starts ┆ ends ┆ concurrent │
│ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---               ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ i64       ┆ i64         ┆ i64       ┆ i64             ┆ i64               ┆ u32    ┆ u32  ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════╪════════╪══════╪════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 0           ┆ 4         ┆ null            ┆ null              ┆ 1      ┆ 0    ┆ null       │
│ 1         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ null            ┆ null              ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ 1          │
│ 2         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ null            ┆ null              ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ 1          │
│ 3         ┆ 3           ┆ 4         ┆ null            ┆ null              ┆ 1      ┆ 0    ┆ 1          │
│ 4         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ 0               ┆ 0                 ┆ 0      ┆ 2    ┆ 2          │
│ 5         ┆ null        ┆ null      ┆ null            ┆ null              ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ 0          │
└───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────┴──────┴────────────┘

